# How to replace the comma by colon within the parenthesis using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want replace the comma(,) into colon (:) within parenthesis only using preg_replace

Input:

```
`parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`type` enum('text','textarea','mail','uri','date','image','checkbox','menu','menu_option','group','frame','history') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
```

Output:

```
`parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` enum('text':'textarea':'mail':'uri':'date':'image':'checkbox':'menu':'menu_option':'group':'frame':'history') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
```

kindly suggest us

Comment: replacing " ',' " for " ':' " doesn't do what you want? Be aware of the litteral apostrophes.

Comment: first catch the whole string between "(" ")", then do what you wish.

Comment: But why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`echo preg_replace('/\'[\s]*\,[\s]*\'/', "':'", $input);`

`\'` matches the character `'` literally

`[\s]*` will remove any spaces between single quote and comma

Comment: is it possible to get the following result

Comment: output => 'text':'textarea':'mail':'uri':'date':'image':'checkbox':'menu':'menu_option':'group':'frame':'history'

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
$a="place your input here";
$b=preg_replace('/\,/', ':', $a); 
echo $a."<br/>";
echo $b;
```